# How to list a Windows process on Ubuntu Terminal in WSL

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Now it's possible to use the Ubuntu terminal or bash shell on Windows.

How can I list Windows processes using `ps` or `htop`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Windows 10 *Bash* You can execute:

```
ps -ef
```

You can also install `htop` using:

```
sudo apt-get install htop
```

And then execute

```
htop
```

**However** the Windows 10 Bash is limited to the user running it.

You won't be able to access Windows 10 system as root.

You can treat it as a limited Ubuntu sandbox in Windows 10

More info [MSDN bash](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/faq)

Comment: While using ps on Windows the only process that it returns to me are those ones running on the terminal. Strange.

Comment: @RodrigoFariasRezino you might want to file a bug. https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1301 was closed because `ifconfig` was fixed, but the report originally included `ps` as well.

Comment: nice muru, I just did it!

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/2110

Comment: @RodrigoFariasRezino - as I wrote in my answer, the Ubuntu Bash in Windows 10, is a kind of sandbox which runs limited version of ubuntu (command line only) which can't access Windows-10 system and limited to the user which runs Windows Bash

Comment: hunnn Yaron, I saw, but I had understood that as I had a process running as a local user it would be listed there. Thanks again for the explanation.

Comment: -1 This is just wrong. those commands don't show *windows* processes. They only show the processes started in WSL. The other answer actually addresses the OP's question.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to list Windows native process, you can call tasklist.exe from your bash. It will return a list of current running Windows processes. In fact, you can call any windows executables from within bash. All you have to do is to add the file extension when calling it:

`tasklist.exe`

Comment: this is useful. you can also type "tasklist /NH /FO CSV" or "tasklist /NH /FO TABLE" to suppress column headers and to output the data as either a set of comma separated  values or as a space formatted table, either of which are pretty friendly from a Linux perspective for command line processing.